# How to append anchors in url through ajax call in dynatree?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, dynatree

I have been trying to call java servlet through ajax calls in dynatree. The problem is how do I add an anchor at the end of the url like this?

```
http://.../TreeBuilder?caller=Applications
```

My jquery code looks like this

```js
onLazyRead: function(node){ 
            node.appendAjax({
                               url: "/TreeBuilder", 
                               data: {"key": node.data.key, 
                                      "mode": "all"
                                      },
                               success: function(node) {
```

My servlet doGet method looks like this

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    String caller = request.getParameter("caller");
    OrganisationService oService = new OrganisationService();
    try {
        // Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\test.json"));

        // loop array
        JSONArray children = null;
        try {
            children = oService.getChildren(caller);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("The children passed are" + children.toJSONString());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(children.toJSONString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The key-value pairs in data object within the function appendAjax actually gets appended at the end of url like this

```
http://.../TreeBuilder?key=value
```

then we can go ahead and get the parameters in the doGet function of the servlet.